# MongoDB different behaviour on .save() and .findOneAndUpdate() for same Geo data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to save a simple Geo coordinate [lng, lat] in MongoDB to be able to use GeoSpatial queries. This is my schema:

Car Schema:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const schema = mongoose.Schema({
  carId: String,
  location: {
    type: {
      type: String,
      enum: ["Point"],
    },
    coordinates: {
      type: [Number],
    },
  },
});

const Car = mongoose.model("cars", schema);
```

Saving new document like this:

```
const newCar = new Car({
   carId: "car1" , 
   location: [74.00912, 34.091218]
});

newCar.save();
```

Adds a new document with `location`: `{ coordinates: [] }`, however **updating** the *same document* like this:

```
Car.findOneAndUpdate({carId: "car1}, {location: [74.00912, 34.091218]});
```

updates the document with `location: [ 74.001, 34.0121 ]` and **Geospatial Queries** work properly!

Why does the same value for `location` works fine while updating and *fails* while saving a new document? What is the correct way of adding and updating Geo data in MongoDB. Is this the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the schema you have defined and the way you want to store location is different.

If you want to store location like this:

```
location: [74.00912, 34.091218]
```

your schema should be this

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  carId: String,
  location: [Number]
});
```

It's working different on save and findOneAndUpdate is because when you save the document, mongoose checks if your document structure matches the schema you have defined and ignores the values and fields that do no match the schema.

Comment: Alright, but will the GeoSpatial queries work if schema is declared like you have done?

Comment: and shouldn't `findOneAndUpdate` also check the document structure before updating the record?